# Merge 2 time series datasets with difference time interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 timeseries datasets. The first dataset is a 10 mins interval record of information from the device with the format below.

| Time_stamp | Device_IDI | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-18 16:10:00 | 645 | 20 |
| 2022-02-18 16:20:00 | 645 | 21 |
| .... |  |  |
| 2022-02-18 16:10:00 | 697 | 20 |
| 2022-02-18 16:20:00 | 697 | 20 |

The second dataset is an event records of device's error.

| Device_IDI | Start | End | Error message | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 645 | 2022-02-18 16:26:05 | 2022-02-19 06:25:17 | temperature error | 13:59:12 |
| 697 | 2022-02-18 16:24:36 | 2022-02-18 16:24:43 | temperature error | 00:00:07 |

Expected output would have time_stamp, device_idi, temperature and error message. With the condition below. I think the example will explain it much better than my words.

| Time_stamp | Device_IDI | Temperature | Error message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-18 16:20:00 | 645 | 20 | temperature error |
| 2022-02-18 16:30:00 | 645 | 20 | temperature error |
| 2022-02-18 16:40:00 | 645 | 20 | temperature error |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 2022-02-19 06:20:00 | 645 | 20 | temperature error |
| 2022-02-19 06:30:00 | 645 | 50 | Null |
| ..... |  |  |  |
| 2022-02-18 16:20:00 | 697 | 20 | temperature error |
| 2022-02-18 16:30:00 | 697 | 20 | Null |

Comment: What is your goal? Doing the work in memory is trivial with any  sorting algorithm.

Comment: My goal is to have 1 time series dataset with 10 mins interval about devices that has events and error messages. Depending on the length of events, i will get the same error message through time. 
You can see that device 645's event lasts almost 14 hours, so i would like to have 84 (14*6) error messages from the time the error starts till it over. 
I hope i explained myself better here.

Comment: So the OP wants to add new columns where `start < timestamp < end`...

Comment: OP wants to have a 10 mins record with timestamp, start and end of an events will be shown in columns Error message (if there is an event) and it will match with the time span of an event. 
Example: an event lasts 30 mins, I would love to see 3 rows with error messages according to when it started (floor time stamp). If an event last <10 mins, there is only 1 row get error message.

Comment: You can use [`piso.lookup`](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/piso.lookup.html#piso.lookup) quite easily here.  If you post code to reproduce example data I'll show you how.